# Generate a String from all values of a specific key from List<Map> in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

Suppose I have a list of Map such as:
(Using json format just for demonstration)

```
List<Map> myList = [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Harie"
    },
    {
        "id": "Forty",
        "location": "Earth"
    },
    {
        "name": "Potah"
    },
    {
        "id": "0"
    }
]
```

Now I want all the "id" values in a single String object, separated by a separator.
For example, the above map should give me:

```
"12#Forty#0"
```

Note:
The order in which they are indexed in the list has to be maintained.
I know I can do it like this:

```
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map map : myList) {
            if (map.get("id") instanceof String) {
                if(result.length()>0){
                    result.append('#');
                }
                result.append(map.get("id"));
            }
        }
        //Use result.toString() for output
```

But I want a more readable and simplified code, preferably using Java stream api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stream and join all the key `id` values which are not null

```
String keyString = myList.stream()
           .map(map->map.get("id"))
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
           .map(Object::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.joining("#"));
```

In case if you want to check if the value is `String` instance you can `filter`

```
filter(val-> val!=null && val instance String)
```

Comment: you would have to perform mapping with `Object#toString` or a cast for the raw type anyway.

Comment: thanks @Naman i missed it, but updated the answer

Answer (score -2):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
myList.stream().map((mapping) => {
   sb.append(mapping.get(id))
   sb.append("#")
}
```

You can add extra logic within the lambda function!

Comment: Need to use `List::forEach` because `Stream::map` requires you return a value. Also, you are causing a side effect in StringBuilder which is not "functional:, and finally the order of `Stream::map` or `List::forEach` is not guaranteed so this response is flawed. Hope this helps.